# What was the result of meta discussion on the "big list" or "resource recommendation" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

What was the result of [this discussion](https://matheducators.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74/should-we-have-a-big-list-tag)?

Comment: For me the result was that Jon and latter developments convinced me (more or less) that no big-list tag is needed.